# button plugin not working for more than one button in MUI NSIS Installer

Tags: installation, plugins, custom-controls, nsis, modern-ui

In GetButtonID function, when more than one button event handler is given ,then it autoexits before showing the Directory MUI page dialog.
But, when only one button event handler is given , then the Directory page is displayed without any problems.

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define IDC_BUTTON_CDRIVEPATH 1200
!define IDC_BUTTON_DDRIVEPATH 1201

;---------------------------------------
;Name and file
Name Remove_ERROR
OutFile solve_error.exe
; -------------------------------

!define MUI_ICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\setup.ico" ;
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\icon.bmp" 
!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP"${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\img.bmp" 
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Docs\Modern UI\licensefile.txt"

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW GetButtonID **    <---in this function only one button event handler works, if two handlers are given , then installer crashes**

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

Function **CDRIVEPATH**
   MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "The Software will be installed in : C Drive"
FunctionEnd

Function **DDRIVEPATH**
   MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "The Software will be installed in : D Drive"
FunctionEnd
;--------------------------------

Function **GetButtonID** 

GetFunctionAddress $R2 CDRIVEPATH 
ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler ${IDC_BUTTON_CDRIVEPATH} $R2 

;when this second button handler is given ,then installer autoexits as soon as it has to show the Directory MUI Page dialog:

GetFunctionAddress $R3 DDRIVEPATH 
ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler ${IDC_BUTTON_DDRIVEPATH} $R3

FunctionEnd

;------------------------------------------------------------------
Section "INSTALL MAIN SOFTWARE" 

SetOutPath $INSTDIR

File /r "myfolder\*.*"

SectionEnd
;------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is caused by bug in ButtonEvent.dll plugin. Get new version of this plugin to resolve it.